# Passar matriz como parâmetro de função?

Tags: c, funções, matriz

Estou estudando o algoritmo de Dijkstra e ainda não tentei usar lista de adjacência. Soube que poderia resolver o problema com uma matriz, mas o fato é que eu não consigo receber a matriz na função.
Se eu colocar o código direto na `main` funciona como esperado.
Este é o protótipo que tentei usar:

```
/*
 * v = grafo em forma de matriz
 * n = qtd de vértices
 * o = origem
 */
int * Dijkstra ( int v[][], int n, int o );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Em C, você precisa especificar o tamanho de todas as dimensões de uma matriz que é argumento de função, exceto o tamanho da dimensão mais à esquerda. Por exemplo, se você definir que suas matrizes sempre serão 100x100, você pode definir o tipo da sua função assim:

```
int * Dijkstra ( int v[100][100], int n, int o );
```

ou assim:

```
int * Dijkstra ( int v[][100], int n, int o );
```

A razão disso vem da forma em que matrizes de C são representadas na memória. As linhas são colocadas sequencialmente em um vetorzão. Por exemplo, a matriz 3x3

```
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90
```

É representada em memória como um vetor de tamanho 9

```
M[i][j] ->    10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
i       ->     0  0  0  1  1  1  2  2  2
j       ->     1  2  3  1  2  3  1  2  3
```

Quando você acessa o campo `(i,j)` da matriz 3x3, o que o C faz por baixo dos panos é acessar o campo `3*i + j` do "vetorzão". Por isso, o compilador tem que saber em tempo de compilação quanta colunas há em cada linha, que é o fator que multiplica o `i`.

Se você não quiser definir as dimensões da sua matriz em tempo de compilação tem algumas alternativas que você pode fazer. A mais comum é usar um vetor de vetores ao invés de uma vetor multidimensional. Assim, sua matriz tem um tipo "vetor de ponteiro pra inteiro" `int **` ao invés do tipo "vetor bidimensional de inteiros 100x100" `int [100][100]`.

```
 M ->  |*| --> [10 20 30]
       |*| --> [40 50 60]
       |*| --> [70 80 90]
```

Um exemplo de como alocar uma matriz MxN:

```
// Alocando a matriz dinâmicamente
int ** mat = malloc((sizeof int*) * M;
int  * buf = malloc((sizeof int) * M * N);
for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
    mat[i] = &buf[N*i];
}

// Usando a matriz:
for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
        mat[i][j] = f(i,j);
    }
 }

 // Libere a memória alocada dinamicamente quando você acabar de usar.
 free(mat);
 free(buf);
```

Comment: Muuuito obrigado! Única coisa que tenho a dizer é que acho que no exemplo da matrix NxM, dentro de todos os for que você usou, vc inverteu o M com N, mas tudo bem! Foi muito útil! Obrigado novamente!

Comment: Prefiro dizer que as primeiras linhas estavam erradas e os for estavam certos :) Fazer NxM com o N antes do M é pedir pra dar confusão...

Comment: hehe... em vez de `M` e `N` (ou `N` e `M`) sugiro o uso de `row` e `col` (ou `linha` e `coluna`)