# Matriz dinâmica como parâmetro em C ou C++?

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz, parâmetros, array-multidimensional

Após horas de pesquisa, não encontrei nada que respondesse minha duvida,ou não consegui entender a resposta. Quero criar uma matriz `NxN` de tamanho variável. Fiz com *ponteiros*,mas quero passar ela como parâmetro entre funções,uma função para preencher, outra para manipular, etc. Porém não está funcionando

Após criar a matriz, como faço para passá-la para outra função? E como deve ser a declaração da outra função para recebê-la?

```
int main()
{
int **campo;
...
campo = alocaMatriz(altura,largura);
popularMatriz(campo); //???e agora rsrs
outraFuncao(campo);//??!?!?!
}

int alocaMatriz(int linha, int coluna)
{
int i,j;
int **campo = (int**)malloc(linha * sizeof(int*)); 

for (i = 0; i < linha; i++)
{
    campo[i] = (int*) malloc(coluna * sizeof(int)); 
    for (j = 0; j < coluna; j++)
    {
        campo[i][j] = 0; //Inicializa com 0.
    }
}
campo[0][0]=1;//adiciona o agente ao tabuleiro
}
outraFuncao(int **campo){} //?????
```

Comment: Utilize a representação em vetor linear de matriz. e passaria por ponteiro único (int \*campo). dai para recuperar a posição seria usando campo[i+linha\*j], e alocamento seria (int\*) malloc(linha \* coluna \* sizeof(int));

Comment: Então não preciso de um ponteiro duplo?não entendi muito bem...sempre que fui alocar matrizes fiz desse jeito x.x buguei

Comment: Ponteiro duplo, não significa uma Matriz. é um Ponteiro para um Ponteiro. Se você pensar como uma matriz é implementada na memória, você verá que quando chega no final de uma linha, ele pula para próxima linha na primeira coluna

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar matriz como parâmetro de função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60065/passar-matriz-como-par%c3%a2metro-de-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 1):

O argumento para as funções deve ser do tipo 'int **', se estás usando uma representação de ponteiro para ponteiro. Via de regra, o argumento para a função deve ser do mesmo tipo da estrutura de dados que está sendo passada, nesse caso, um ponteiro para ponteiro de inteiros.

Exemplo:

```
void popularMatriz(int **campo);

int main(){
    int **campo = alocaCampo(linhas, colunas);
    popularMatriz(campo);
}
```

Comment: cara, valeu! resolveu  o problema kkk obrigado.

Comment: Opa, seria bom marcares essa resposta como certa, então ;-)